# Liberty Server in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, websphere-liberty

We currently use Eclipse for editing and testing our Java WebSphere APIs via the Liberty Runtime server.  I'd like to switch using VSCode, which I know supports Java and Maven.  Is there any way to integrate the Liberty Runtime with VSCode for localhost testing?

Answer (score 0):

Liberty has maven and gradle plugins available, and the APIs/runtime are available as maven dependencies.

Here are some useful links:

- [Liberty gradle plugin](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.gradle) (works for OpenLiberty and WAS Liberty)
- [Liberty maven plugin](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven) (works for OpenLiberty and WAS Liberty)
- [WAS Liberty features and APIs as Maven deps](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver)
- [OpenLiberty features and APIs as Maven deps](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.openliberty.features)

The only thing that you will get with Eclipse and not VS Code is the WebSphere Developer Tools (WDT) Eclipse plugin, which gives a UI for creating, starting, stopping, and configuring servers.